# Page Refresh After 401 Response from Network Request

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have some code in a custom service that is returning the following:

```
public myMethod(
    server: string,
    id: string): Observable<any> {
        const url: string = ...;

        const headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Authorization', 'Token=' + this._token);
        const options = new RequestOptions({headers});

        const body = {
            server,
            id
        };

        return this.httpClient.post(url, body)
            .map(res => res.json())
            .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json()));
    }
```

When I subscribe to this call, I handle the error in the following way:

```
this.myService.myMethod(server, id)
    .subscribe(data => {
        this.x = 'hello';
        this.y = 'world';
        this.z = '!';

        data.propertyOne = this.myForm.get('someProperty').value;
        data.propertyTwo = this.myForm.get('someOtherProperty').value;

        this.myForm.patchValue({
            key: data;
        });

        this.myEventEmitter.emit(someValue);
        this.myOtherEventEmitter.emit(someOtherValue);
    }, (err) => {
        if (err.Code === 401) {
            event.preventDefault(); // is this needed?
            // some more stuff here
        }
    });
```

What ends up happening (and this is the reason I tried using `event.preventDefault()`), and I'm not sure if this is because of the `401`, is that the page refreshes itself instead of handling the error gracefully and continuing with the execution of the program.

Is this a common issue? Any ideas on how to get around it?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share all the code of subscribe ?

Comment: I added the structure of it. The insides aren't really relevant. Only simple declarations are taking place inside of the success call.

Comment: Where does `event` come from?

Comment: I think .prevenDefault() is misplaced here, that's used for example in input events in the DOM. We'd need a bit more info about your code, both pieces are somewhat out of context... ;-)

Comment: I added some more code which hopefully is a bit more clarifying.

Comment: Does that page still refresh if there is no error?

Comment: @bygrace No, only when there is an error will it refresh

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console? Can you debug and tell us the last line to execute before the redirect? Does any of the code in "stuff here" do a redirect? Is the action triggered from within a form?

Comment: The only "error" that comes up is the one from the network request, a 401. I stuck a console.log() in there which gets executed. The entirety of the `err` block is executed before the page refreshes. The 401 in this case would ideally be caught, and then a modal would open up prompting a user for credentials.

Comment: Can you set 'preserve log' in the console so that you can verify that no errors occurred that are cleared on refresh? Besides that I think that we need more context. Though you may not think the rest of the code is relevant it might be. What would be most helpful is if you could create a reproducible example on stackblitz.com or something similar.

Comment: What happens when you delete event.preventDefault() ?

Comment: @bygrace After preserving the log, there were still no errors indicating that anything happened other than the network request "failure" (the 401). I'll try and mock what I'm doing inside and update the post accordingly.

Comment: @bygrace I don't mean to dummy down the code so much but the content is nearly identical to what I'm doing, the only difference are the variable names.

Comment: I am having this issue as well, only in my case it occurs when I add query params to the endpoint I am hitting. A 401 from the same endpoint sans query params is handled gracefully, with forced reload. My working theory is that 401s from certain server endpoints are whitelisted somewhere on my network or in the code, and that the query params are not matched by the naked endpoint in the whitelist.